# Magento 2 - mesg: URL key for specified store already exists.and I know it doesn't

Tags: magento2, url-key

In Magento 2, when I try to change URL key for a category, I get this message:`"URL key for specified store already exists."`. This is my code:

```
$this->logger->log("id is: " . $c->getId(), true);
$c->load($c->getId());
$newUrlKey=$c->getUrlKey() . "-baba" . $count++;
$this->logger->log($newUrlKey, true);
$c->setUrlKey($newUrlKey);
$this->logger->log($c->getData(), true);

$c->save();
```

But I know there is no other category with this url key. What is the problem with Magento here?

Comment: Hi @vladimir-despotovic, I have a similar issue - when creating products. For me, it happens when the first url key I try to add exists. I catch the error and try to save the same product several times with a bunch of different url keys (including an incremental counter). This fails with the error message you quote.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to url_key on the category you are trying to save. Most probably there is some rewrite with the same key for the category link added as redirect. Check url_rewrite table for rows with request_path containing the url_key of the category you are trying to save.

Comment: the problem is that this is the root category and it looks like this error always raises, no matter which url key I choose.

Comment: Looks like this error is unavoidable. Yes, I tried to put a random name for the url key (jibble jabble word) and it disn't work(ie.error is raised again)

Comment: Because there is some old redirect in url_rewrite table. Dump url_rewrite table to a backup file and clear it. Then try to save the category. It should work. I think the problem occurs when you have multiple store, sets url_key first for default which creates rewrites for all stores and then changes it in the store scope without unchecking "keep the old redirect" which creates a rewrite from default name to the current one as 301.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't solve the probem. I deleted everything from url_rewrite, and the problem appears on root and also on another category. I didn't notice until now.